# jQuery - Undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I include some scripts and there is error undefined is not a function.
I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('.class-name').each(function() {
          $(this).appear(function() {
               $(this).delay(150).animate({opacity: 1, left: "0px"}, 1000);});
        });
});
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `appear()` I don't think there is a function as such.

Comment: `use fadeIn`  instead

Comment: the `$` becomes the new variable (not alias of `jQuery`) in your `function($)`) try using another variable name.

Comment: `jQuery.appear` is a library. Have you included to your document? and which one you are using include the target link.

Comment: Here is the screenshoot if it helps http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a22u0tw82

Comment: Split Your code into a lines - each function in new line

Comment: I need to include jQuery.appear library to work :) Thanks Rahil!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the "$" var, as you pass it as argument of your callback. Try using your callback with no argument, like that :

```
//jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.class-name').each(function() {
        $(this).appear(function() {$(this).delay(150).animate({opacity: 1, left: "0px"}, 1000);});
    });
});
```

Hope it will help...